# How to use vb.net dataset, data are from manual added rows and show it to tablix RDLC?

Tags: vb.net, dataset, rdlc

Can you help me? Im having this error when I click the button. It says A data source instance has not been supplied for the Data source 'BatchCodeGenerator'. And I have my Dataset.xsd also added, I dont know if it helps

```
Private Sub btnPreviewReport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPreviewReport.Click

Dim DataTable1 As DataTable = New DataTable("DataTable1")
DataTable1.Columns.Add("CardNo", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
DataTable1.Rows.Add("22-001")
DataTable1.Rows.Add("22-002")
    
    
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\Reports\BatchBarcodeGenerator.rdlc"
    
    
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("BatchBarcodeGenerator", DataTable1))
    
Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the error message is correct (`BatchCodeGenerator`) than you are using a wrong name for your `ReportDataSource` (`BatchBarcodeGenerator`).

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("BatchCodeGenerator", DataTable1))
```